# Convert Python program to Arduino sketch

Tags: embedded

This is what I currently use to read data from a meter in Python.

```py
import serial
import time

SNRM = "7EA00703619369477E"
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
ser.write(bytes.fromhex(SNRM))
time.sleep(1)
data = ser.read_all().hex()
print(data)
```

I want to write the same program in the Arduino IDE (for Arduino Uno). Please help me, I am new in programming.

Answer (score 3):

Here an attempted port of your Python code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial sensorPort(2, 3); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello!");
  
  sensorPort.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  byte snrm[] = { 0x7E, 0xA0, 0x07, 0x03, 0x61, 0x93, 0x69, 0x47, 0x7E };
  sensorPort.write(snrm, sizeof(snrm));
  
  delay(1000);
  
  byte data[32] = { 0 };
  int bytesAvailable = sensorPort.available();
  int bytesRead = sensorPort.readBytes(data, bytesAvailable);

  String out{"0x"};
  
  for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
    String hexStr{data[i], HEX};
    if (hexStr.length() < 2) {
      out += "0";
    }
    out += hexStr;
  }

  Serial.println(out);
}
```

This is untested and probably needs some more tweaking.

As the Arduino Uno only has one serial port, which is normally used for sending debug traces to the computer, I used a software serial port as described [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LibraryExamples/SoftwareSerialExample).

Maybe you also want to have a look at the examples that come with the IDE which you can find under: File > Examples

Comment: Neat - I didn't know about [`SoftwareSerial`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/softwareSerial)

Comment: @Ezra Thanks for your support, your answer help for me. I have stuck some other problem in this code. Actually, the thing is that we are having multiple arrays which are of byte type and I want to create an array of int type having the reference of all these byte array and then I can iterate them. Iteration makes my code more efficient and very optimized.

Comment: and then make them a integer array and then iterate them over the following code
byte auth[]= {0x7E, 0xA0, 0x2B, 0x03, 0x61, 0x32, 0x8D, 0xEB, 0xE6,0x7E};
  byte volt[]= {0x7E, 0xA0, 0x190xC0, 0x01,0xBC, 0x96, 0x7E};
  byte freq[]={0x7E, 0xA0, x00, 0xC0, 0x9E, 0x7E};
  sensorPort.write(snrm, sizeof(snrm));
  byte data[] = { 0 };
 int bytesAvailable = sensorPort.available();int  bytesRead = sensorPort.readBytes(data, bytesAvailable);
String  out={"0x"};  
  for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
    String hexStr{data[i], HEX};
    out += hexStr;}

Comment: > your answer help for me.

How about accepting the answer then?

Comment: I do not quite follow what you are trying to achieve. How about creating a dedicated question for that? Maybe with some pseudo code to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you are going to do that on an Aduino Unu as it only supports one serial port (the serial port is exposed on the I/O header and connected to the USB-to-TTL Serial converter chip.  You need one to connect to your "meter" and one to which to "print" the output.

Moreover the serial pins are TTL level not RS-232 level, you may need to add a line-driver to connect the serial port to your meter. If you are not building your own, consider an [RS232 Shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/13029).  That would leave the hardware UART available for "printing" output and programming the device.

If you want to "print" the data you will need an Arduino with an additional port. A Mega, Uno WiFi, Zero, or Due (ARM based) for example.  Or perhaps a display "shield" ([example)](https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/arduino-lcd-keypad-shield). [**edit**: or use a [`SoftwareSerial`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/softwareSerial) object as suggested by Ezra Bühler].

Assuming you actually want to do something with the data other than "print" it, then the following will perform a read every second (there are any number of other solutions), but discards the data - you need to figure out what to do with it:

```
void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(1000) ;
}

void loop()
{
  static const uint8_t SNRM[] = { 0x7E, 0xA0, 0x07, 0x03, 0x61, 0x93, 0x69, 0x47, 0x7E } ;
  static uint8_t read_buffer[128] ;

  Serial.write( SNRM, sizeof(SNRM) ) ;
  size_t count = Serial.readBytes( read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer) ) ;
  
  // Do something with the data here
  
}
```

The above assumes 9600,N,8,1 serial frames.  Change as necessary.  You have also not specified what your "meter" outputs or the length of the response. You have to allow sufficient buffer length - I have allowed 128 bytes which may be ample - again for you to change as required.

However I suggest that you learn about the Arduino hardware and Sketch programming (essentially a C++ framework in an environment that "hides" some of the more complex details).

Comment: Earlier, I was using USB to RS-232 converter which was able to communicate with the meter and return data. In my earlier setup, the USB-RS-232 converter was connected to the meter's optical port through the optical cable. 
So, after some research, I found this [TTL-RS-232 converter](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07VHZQM5C/ref=cm_sw_r_wa_apa_fabc_1Z7CQXBYYY756WH9VXNT) through which I was able to bypass the USB-RS232 converter and directly connected the optical cable to the TTL-RS 232 converter, which is connected to the arduino uno's UART port.

Comment: I tried using the code shared by @Ezra Bühler but I am still unable to obtain any response from the meter. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/GmsjgrS) is an image of my setup, hope it makes sense.

Comment: @ManishGupta Clearly, if you are using Ezra's code you should post your comment to his answer not mine.  SO is a Q&A, not a discussion forum. In any case  your problem is now a different question than how to translate your PC Python script to Arduino C++.  You should post a new question.  However this is partly a hardware issue, so may be off topic.  A schematic would make more sense than a photograph in any case.  Also a link to the meter manual and the code you are using.